# Looping through folders and calling batch files when found

Tags: batch-file

I have an hierarchy of folders, some folders have "DoWork.cmd" files that I need to execute.
I have the following command:

```
for /r %%x in (*.cmd) do call "DoWork.cmd"
```

I am getting the following error:

> call "DoWork.cmd" '"DoWork.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: `for /r %%x in (*.cmd) do if /i "%%~nxx"=="DoWork.cmd" call "%%~x"`

Comment: that works, but how do I set current working directory to the location of the found file ?

Comment: For /r %%x in (DoWork?.cmd) Do cd "%%~dpx"&%%x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check to make sure you are executing the correct batch file and will set the working directory to the directory of the batch file.

```
@echo off
for /r %%x in (*.cmd) do (
    if /i "%%~nxx"=="DoWork.cmd" (
        pushd "%%~dpx"
        call "%%~x"
        popd
    )
)
```